# I want to know when someone makes a phone call, what will the signal received from a phone look like?

Tags: mobile, microcontroller, gsm

I am learning to rewrite the code for the microcontroller integrated in the development Sim modules (such as Sim800C) to be able to control switching a device without having to use another MCU. If we can do that, we only need to add 1 transistor to be able to control a relay on and off.
I know at the output of the MCU (eg STM32F...) inside the sim module (eg sim800C) there will be a function to receive and read personal information stored in the sim card and decode the signal emitted from the Mobile base station: For example, when a call comes in, it will generate the sequence:
RING
+CLIP: "01203360211",161,"",0,"",0
....
So can anyone help me to know when the MCU outputs a string like the above, what will be its input 11110000,...? or something special in some form? I'm really confused. Thanks everyone!

Comment: what happened when you tried one of the existing examples or libraries?

Comment: did you read the datasheet/documentation?

Comment: Yes, I perfectly understand your question.  You need to continue to read the documentation.  What libraries did you try?  What did they show?  Does not appear that you have done much work and expect us to do it for you.  That is not what stackoverflow is for.  Nor is it here to search or read documentation nor libraries for you.   Please ask a proper stackoverflow question.